# How to find the number of nodes in finite element model

Tags: finite-element-method

I am using *Mathematica* version 10 to solve a 2-D elliptic equation by the finite element method.  I created a finite element model with a very fine mesh.  Would you please suggest me a command to show the total number of nodes in the model.  This is because it is difficult to find it from the plot.

Comment: Try `Length[ifun["ElementMesh"]["Coordinates"]]` where `ifun` is the generated `InterpolatingFunction`.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Ilian's comment, but modified to fit your situation.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
Ω = 
  MeshRegion[
    {{0, 0}, {2/Sqrt[3], 0}, {1/Sqrt[3], 1}}, 
    {Line[{{1, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}}]}]; 
mesh = ToElementMesh[Ω, MaxCellMeasure -> 0.01, "MeshOrder" -> 1];
mesh["Coordinates"] // Length
```

> ```
> 59
> ```